# Laravel livewire query string not working in url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, query-string, laravel-livewire

I am trying to add a filter functionality by categories in an ecommerce site using laravel livewire query strings but I am not able to understand why it is not working

this is the blade file code:

```
<div class="filter-items">
                    @foreach ($categories as $category)

                    <div class="item">
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" wire:model="categoryInputs[]"  value="{{ $category->id }}">
                            <div> @error('categoryInputs'){{ $message }}@enderror </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>{{ $category->name }}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @endforeach
            </div>
```

this is the component code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Frontend\Product;

use App\Models\Product;
use Livewire\Component;

class Index extends Component
{
    public $products, $categories, $categoryInputs=[];


    protected $queryString = [
        'categoryInputs' => ['except' => '', 'as' => 'category']
    ];

    public function mount($categories)
    {
        $this->categories = $categories;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        $this->products = Product:: when($this->categoryInputs, function ($q){
            $q->whereIn('category_id', $this->categoryInputs);
            })
            // ->with('productImagesMain')
            ->where('status', 1)
            ->get();


        return view('livewire.frontend.product.index', [
            'products' => $this->products,
            'categories' => $this->categories
        ]);

    }
}
```

this is the model of Product which consists a column category_id which I am using to sort the data:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'products';

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id',
        'name',
        'small_description',
        'description',
        'original_price',
        'selling_price',
        'quantity',
        'status',
        'material',
        'dimensions',
        'trending'
    ];

    public function productImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
    public function productImagesMain()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class, 'product_id', 'id')->where('main', 1);
    }
    public function productSizes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductSize::class, 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And the route :

```
// frontend controllers
Route::controller(FrontendController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index')->name('index');
    Route::get('product-view', 'product_view')->name('frontend.productview');
    Route::get('product-details/{product_details:name}/view', 'product_details')->name('frontend.productDetails');
});
```

this is controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class FrontendController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::select('products.*', 'product_images.image')
            ->leftJoin('product_images', 'products.id', '=', 'product_images.product_id')
            ->where('product_images.main', '=', 1)
            ->where('products.status', '=', 1)
            ->get();

        return view('index', compact('products'));
    }

    public function product_view()
    {
        $categories = Category::where('status', 1)->get();
        return view('productview', compact('categories'));
    }

    public function product_details(Product $product_details)
    {
        $product = Product::with('productImages', 'productSizes')
            ->where('id', $product_details->id)
            ->first();

        return view('productdetails', compact('product'));
    }
}
```

I have tried the online documentation of Livewire query string but couldn't resolve the error.

My expectation is when I click on a checkbox of category game, then it should form a query string like: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product-view?categoryInputs[0]=games` but now it is like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product-view` even after I click the checkboxes. Please help me fix the issue.

Comment: Your controller code is wrong. You've pasted your component code. Share your controller code too

Comment: AFAIK, you cant use `array` in query strings since characters like `[` and `]` will be converted to url unicode.

Comment: i have taken reference from this video. It follows the same method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PpxVfI55jU&list=PLRheCL1cXHruG6bV4tAIF4AhkUMaABf3F&index=28

Comment: @HassaanAli updated please check

Comment: Are you on Livewire 2 or 3?

Comment: @Yinci its livewire 3

Comment: I have researched a lot but still couldn't find the solution what could be the problem any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt it would make a difference, but if you update the `$queryString` prop as per [the docs](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading#url-query-string), does it make a difference?

Comment: tried, but still no change it seems like its not able to form the search query

Comment: could you share this problem so that I could get some more clues